# Change the site's name to Science Fiction or Sci-Fi

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Last I checked, this site is dominated by Sci-Fi questions. Also, referring to this site is a pain in ass. Concise name would be awesome.

If fantasy guys are pissed, the new name can be *Death Star*. Star Wars is both Science Fiction and Fantasy.

What do you think?

**Update:**
I am giving reference of *Ask Different* site which by no means displays any connection with Apple.

Comment: Based on your comment to the current answer, it sounds like your request is mostly just to make the name shorter, and the thing about accurately reflecting our demographics is secondary. If you edit your question to focus on what's actually motivating the request, you may get answers which more clearly address your actual concern.

Comment: Honestly this is just a bad idea all round.

Answer (score 12):

**No.**

The second most frequently used tag is Harry Potter - currently with 2099 questions.

In fact, of the top five tags, two are science-fiction (Star Trek, Star Wars), and two are Fantasy (Harry Potter, Lord of the Rings). Totaling up their questions, the Science Fiction and Fantasy camps are neck and neck.

There is no reason to change the name.

Comment: Okay. What about *Death Star* (or, something similar) option?

Comment: Deathstar.stackexchange.com is hardly indicative of what the site is, nor is it inclusive of our fantasy aspect - or pretty much any subject other than Star Wars, specifically.

Comment: @SS If you're looking for a name change just so it's easier for you to type or say, try "SF&F." (And franchise-specific names are especially doomed.)